# Handling row selection from a simple grid using jquery and asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Using a simple table and jquery, how would you manually handle selection on a simple table/grid using jquery?

Here's what I've tried. You could check it out or provide your own way of selection. If there's something better or something you know that works, you don't have to read mine. I'd be happy to learn how others are doing it.

---

So far, I've managed to add a `gridrowselected` class on the `tr` when the click event is called so that I'll know which row is currently selected. But I don't know how to pass the selected data back to the controller (or at least an index I placed on the row).

Using a grid like this

```
<table id="ProjectList" class="grid reduced-full-span-grid grid-header">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="long-col">
                Title
            </th>
            <th class="medium-col">
                Type
            </th>
            <th class="medium-col">
                Priority
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% for ( int i = 0; i < Model.Projects.Count; ++i )
           { %>
        <tr class="gridrow">
            <td>
                <%= Html.HiddenFor( model => model.Projects[i].ProjectId ) %>
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor( model => model.Projects[i].Title,
                    new { @readonly = "readonly" } )%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor( model => model.Projects[i].ProjectType,
                    new { @readonly = "readonly" } )%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBoxFor( model => model.Projects[i].Priority,
                    new { @readonly = "readonly" } )%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and selection logic like this

```
$(function() {
    $('.gridrow').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.gridrow').removeClass('gridrow-selected');
        if ($(this).hasClass('gridrow-selected') == true) {
            $(this).removeClass('gridrow-selected');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('gridrow-selected');
        }
        $(this).change();
    });
});
```

I tried something like this

```
$(function() {
    $('#ProjectList .gridrow').click(function() {
        // Get row's index
        var projectId = $(this).find('input[name$=ProjectId]').val();
        // Remove the input if it already exists
        var parentForm = $(this).parents('form');
        parentForm.remove('input[name="selectedRows"]');
        // If it is selected, create the form. If it's not selected then the input just gets removed (the user must have clicked on it and deselected the row)
        if ($(this).hasClass('gridrow-selected') === true) {
            parentForm.append($('<input>', { type: "hidden", name: "selectedRows", value: projectId }));
        }
    });
});
```

which I'm expecting to create a hidden input so that when I post, selectedRows gets passed onto the controller. But all it does is create the input, but the data still doesn't get passed to the controller.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me from this code.  Can you post some of the generated grid html?

Comment: you can look here how the rows are selected using jquery http://mrgsp.md:8080/awesome/lookupdemo (click on a small button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using textboxes, the table row is editable - it might be easier to include a selected property in your project model. Including a single selectedrow property in your top level model would also simplify things a lot so you just need to update a single known field on click rather than making complex dom changes. With both these options you can start with a checkbox/textbox rather than a hidden field so it is very clear what is happening.

Another improvement would be to add an id to the table row - that way your update js is simplified to something like

```
$("#selectedRows").val($(".gridrow-selected").attr("id"));
```

Comment: Nice! Tons easier than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
parentForm.append($('<input>', { type: "hidden", name: "selectedRows", value: projectId }));
```

try

```
parentForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="selectedRows" value="' + projectId + '" />');
```

Comment: Does that change anything? The results seem the same.